# What is the local structure of a fibration?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

It's sometimes said that a fibration is a fiber bundle which is not locally trivial. I'd like to make this precise, by identifying the "local models" on which fibrations are modeled.

Here I'd like the "local models" to be something more enlightening than just "all fibrations". This will be impossible if one doesn't restrict to paracompact bases; I'd be happy even if the base is restricted to be a CW complex. For that matter, I'd be happy if it could be done over a manifold!

**Definition.**

- A ***class of local models*** is a pair $(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F})$ where

  1. $\mathcal{U}$ is a subcategory of spaces, closed under intersection of open embeddings (in the examples here $\mathcal U$ is just all of $\mathsf{Top}$, but it seems natural to include it as a parameter)
  2. For each $U \in \mathcal{U}$ we have a subcategory $\mathcal{F}_U \subseteq \mathsf{Top}/U$ of all maps over $U$, stable under pullback along open embeddings.
- A map $p: E \to B$ is ***locally in $(\mathcal U, \mathcal F)$*** if $B$ admits an open cover $B = \cup_i U_i$ such that

  1. each $U_i \in \mathcal U$
  2. each pullback $E|_{U_i} \to U_i$ is in $\mathcal{F}_{U_i}$ (up to homeomorphism)
  3. each transition map $E|_{U_i}|_{U_i \cap U_j} \to E|_{U_j}|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_{U_i \cap U_j}$.

**Remark.** Of course, really "being locally in $(\mathcal U, \mathcal{F})$" is a structure and not a property as suggested by the terminology -- $E \to B$ could be locally in $(\mathcal U, \mathcal{F})$ in many different ways (so the above definition really should be neatened up a bit -- I hope it's clear how to do this). With this in mind, it is natural to generalize the definition, replacing $(\mathcal U, \mathcal{F})$ by an arbitrary fibration over $\mathsf{Top}$ equipped with a map of fibrations to the codomain fibration $\mathsf{Top} \downarrow \mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Top}$. But I think this extra generality is not needed for the following.

**Examples.**

1. A map $p: E \to B$ is a fiber bundle iff it is locally in $(\mathsf{Top}, \mathsf{Triv})$ where $\mathsf{Triv}_U$ is the category of projections $F \times U \to U$ and homeomorphisms between them.
2. A map $p: E \to B$ is a fiber bundle with structure group $G$ iff it is locally in $(\mathsf{Top}, \mathsf{Triv}_G)$ where $(\mathsf{Triv}_G)_U$ consists of projection maps $F \times U \to U$ where $F$ is one among a specific list of $G$-spaces, and $G$-equivariant maps.
3. [Hurewicz and Huebsch] (**Key example!**) If $B$ is paracompact, a map $p: E \to B$ is a fibration iff it is locally a fibration, i.e. locally in the class $(\mathsf{Top}, \mathsf{Fib})$, where $\mathsf{Fib}_U$ is the class of all fibrations over $U$, and homeomorphisms between them.
4. (Less important) A smooth manifold is an identity map $B = B$ which is locally modeled on $\mathcal{U}$ being open subsets of Euclidean space and smooth maps, and $\mathcal{F}_U$ consisting of identity maps.

**Question.** Is there a class $(\mathcal U, \mathcal{F})$ *smaller* than $(\mathsf{Top}, \mathsf{Fib})$ (Example 3) such that for paracompact $B$, a map $p: E \to B$ is a fibration iff it is locally in $(\mathcal U, \mathcal{F})$?

I'd be happy with an answer that only works with further conditions on the topology of the fiber or the base.

Of course, one could take $\mathcal{U}$ to be an arbitrary collection of spaces such that every point in every space has a neighborhood contained in $\mathcal{U}$, with $\mathcal{F}$ being all fibrations over such spaces. This is not very enlightening *per se*, but e.g. if there's a particular choice of such $\mathcal{U}$ that sheds some light on the situation, that would be interesting.

I also haven't been specific about what kind of fibration I'm talking about. I think I'd be happy with any version -- Hurewicz, Serre -- even quasifibrations would be interesting.

**Analogy to algebraic geometry.** If we replace $\mathsf{Top}$ by the category of schemes (or even by functors $\mathsf{CRing} \to \mathsf{Set}$), then a quasicoherent sheaf on a scheme is modeled locally on modules over affine schemes. And a vector bundle is just a locally free coherent sheaf. So in algebraic geometry, there's something interesting to say about the local structure even of non-locally-trivial quasicoherent sheaves. I'm wondering if in topology, there's likewise something interesting to say about non-locally-trivial fibrations.

Comment: Aren't all Hurewicz fibrations locally homotopy trivial? I believe this goes by way of Dold fibrations.

Comment: See for instance https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~pavesic/RESEARCH/A%20note%20on%20trivial%20fibrations.pdf